# I'm trying to make a select component in React but onChange listener is not working

Tags: reactjs, select, onchange

I want to make a select country component in my Form but in my `<select>` onChange listener is not working for some reason

```
<Form.Group className="form-group">
       <Form.Label htmlFor="country">Country</Form.Label>
        <div className="form-control-wrap">
             <select className="form-select form-select-lg" id="country" name="country"
                    onChange={e => console.log("Changed")}>
                    <option value={"select-country"}>Select Country</option>
                    {
                       countries.map((c) => {
                             return (<option value={c.name}>{c.name}</option>)})}
            </select>
       </div>
</Form.Group>
```

When I select a country nothing gets printed on the console when "Changed" should be printed there

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is, it works. Can you create a code-snipped like this to reproduce your bug?

```js
const countries = [{ name: 'germany' }];

const App = () => {
 return (
    <select className="form-select form-select-lg" id="country" name="country"
      onChange={e => console.log("Changed")}>
          <option value="select-country">Select Country</option>
          {countries.map((c) => <option value={c.name}>{c.name}</option>)}
    </select>
  )
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">hi</div>
```